# resolve property of .state does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to use `ui-router` resolve property to simply check just before entering that state whether user is logged in or not by using `AuthService` function but it gives no result.

- angular v 1.5.8
- angular-ui.router v 0.2.18

#### index.route.js

```
angular.module('app').config(routerConfig);

  /** @ngInject */
function routerConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, USER_ROLES) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "app/views/dashboard_2.html",
        data: { requiresAuth: true, pageTitle: 'Dashboard', authorizedRoles: ['admin'] } ,
        resolve: {
          isLoggedin: ['AuthService', function(AuthService) {
              return AuthService.isAuthenticated();
          }]
        }
      })
});
```

#### auth.service.js

```
'use strict';
angular
.module('app')
.factory('AuthService', function($log, $http, $q, $cookies){
    var authService = {};
    // .. login and logout methods...
    authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
      return !!$cookies.getObject('currentUser');
    };

    return authService;
});
```

#### index.run.js

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .run(function($rootScope, $state, $log, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS) {
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
                // $log.debug('state change starts');
                $log.debug(to.resolve);

            });
```

I read that resolve return promise object , but I have simple function whcih return true/false

is that the problem? Kindly suggest me what to do in proper way so that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `resolve` function expects a promise, you should return a promise. Modify your code like:

```
isLoggedin: ['AuthService', '$q', function(AuthService, $q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var isLoggedIn = AuthService.isAuthenticated();

    if (isLoggedIn) {
       defer.resolve();
    } else {
       defer.reject();
    }

    return defer.promise;
}]
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `resolve` keyword from your state configuration and modify your `run` block like this:

```
angular
        .module('app')
        .run(function ($rootScope, $state, $log, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS) {
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, from, fromParams) {
                if (toState.name === 'dashboard') {
                    if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                        // Do not allow navigation to state
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // Redirect to somewhere else like login page
                        //$state.go('login')
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

**Edit**

You can modify the above (2nd approach) code to make it generic like this:

```
angular
        .module('app')
        .run(function ($rootScope, $state, $log, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS) {
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, from, fromParams) {
                if (toState.requireAuthenticationFoo && !AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                    // Do not allow navigation to state
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // Redirect to somewhere else like login page
                    //$state.go('login')
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
```

Now use the key `requireAuthenticationFoo` in your state configuration:

```
state('dashboard', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    templateUrl: "app/views/dashboard_2.html",
    data: {requiresAuth: true, pageTitle: 'Dashboard', authorizedRoles: ['admin']},
    requireAuthenticationFoo: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. which is preferred way to use?

Comment: I suggest you use the 2nd way since you are not using the promise. Then, you also will have option to secure your other states.

Comment: but by this 2nd approach , I need to check for each and every child state as well. isn't it?  that means multiple if conditions for each state in .run block